# Filtering only the last 5 newest submissions

Tags: google-sheets-api

Im trying to create a search page that show all entries based on a desired room #. But if there are more than 20 entries, it will screw up the format of the entire sheet. My goal is to only show the latest 5 entries for that one specific room. Any suggestions? I can provide the link to the foru
[Image of the Sheet search panel and circle area to show results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fddxv.png)